# How to "dock" empathy to side of desktop (Digsby style)

Tags: 11.04, gnome, empathy

I come from a windows background, and one of the coolest apps I used was [Digsby](http://www.digsby.com/).

It was a multi-protocol IM client similar in function to empathy.

Now I like empathy, especially when used with gnome3.

One feature digsby had was the ability to dock it to one side of your desktop, when your mouse collided with that side the contact list would show.

I am looking for the ability to do something similar, or, event better would be the ability to set it to show if I bounce my mouse to the top right corner.

Is there anything that would allow me to do this?

Comment: I'm sure that is not possible yet, someone will have to create a gnome extension for that, or you can submit a bug asking for a feature like that in empathy.

Comment: I want that feature for Pidgin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Terribly sorry that this is two weeks late, but I haven't had the internet besides at work, and there's a firewall there. Here goes...)

First download wmctrl by entering this into your terminal `sudo apt-get install wmctrl`

Next, you'll need compiz `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

Then, within compiz, in the "Commands" section add `wmctrl -R "Contact List"` Then, from the Edge Bindings tab, select an edge to associate with that command. (if you don't want it to appear instantly, set a time delay in the General section of compiz)

Hope that works for what you need. And once again, sorry the answer came so late.

Comment: If it's no inconvenience, you should provide the step by step instructions anyways.

Comment: please, that would be awesome